# cocos2d facebook integration failed

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, cocos2d-iphone

i tried the tutorial here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/3392
(the facebook api link is not available any more, i get it from somewhere else

this line in my MainScene(which is the GameScene in the tutorial)

```
 FBSession* _session;
```

the error message is : FBSession: unknown type name

and the header file:

```
 #import "FBConnect/FBConnect.h"
```

has error,but

```
 #import "FBConnect.h"
```

is ok

also i can't find the facebook icon in the source code anymore
please help me with it. i can't find any newer tutorials

I searched online, the FBSession is available in the old sdk, but for the new sdk, there is no 'FBSession.h' file

is there any new tutorial of it???

////////////////
I tried a lot of app today(e.g. fruit ninja). They don't have "actual" facebook/twitter integration. when i click the icon, it just jumps to the facebook page of the app in the browser. 
So can i just create an app on facebook/twitter, then copy down the app's profile page and just link it from my app? is it a common approach??

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the search path for FBConnect in bundle settings. Fixing it the way you've done it will also be correct and will not cause any functional errors

Comment: how? FBSession cant not be found

Comment: could you find a new tutorial for me? it's 1 year old, i heard that facebook api has changed already.

Comment: compile error... no JSON files. could you send me a sample project? i think you missed some of the files. also does the tutorial work?

Comment: dude, i am using cocos2d. quite different. i get compile time error

Comment: @tipycalFlow let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2395/discussion-between-lets-spot-it-and-tipycalflow)

Comment: no JSON file something. your project is not a cocos2d project.

Comment: I'm not sure why it does'nt work but you can check this http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/356